# Insert data in codeigniter

Tags: model-view-controller

I am trying to make an insert function in codeigniter using php and bootstrap. But when i press add button, nothing happens, my new data are not added in my db table. Please Help me. 
My code:

department.php

```
<?php
/* 
 * File Name: employee.php
 */
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class department extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        //load the employee model
        $this->load->model('department_model');
    }

    //index function
    function index()
    {
        //fetch data from department and designation tables
       // $data['department'] = $this->department_model->get_department();

        //set validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('id', 'Employee ID', 'trim|required|numeric');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('department_emer', 'Department Name', 'trim|required|callback_alpha_only_space');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pershkrimi', 'Description', 'trim|required');

        //$this->form_validation->set_rules('id_departament', 'Department', 'callback_combo_check');



        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            //fail validation
            $this->load->view('department_view');
        }
        else
        {    
            //pass validation
            $data = array(
                //'id' => $this->input->post('id'),

                'department_emer' => $this->input->post('department_emer'),
                'pershkrimi' => $this->input->post('pershkrimi'),

            );

            //insert the form data into database
            $this->db->insert('department', $data);

            //display success message
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Department details added to Database!!!</div>');
            redirect('department/index');
        }

    }



    //custom validation function to accept only alpha and space input
    function alpha_only_space($str)
    {
        if (!preg_match("/^([-a-z ])+$/i", $str))
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('alpha_only_space', 'The %s field must contain only alphabets or spaces');
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

department_model.php

```
<?php
/* 
 * File Name: employee_model.php
 */
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class department_model extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }

    //get department table to populate the department name dropdown



}
?>
```

department_view.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CodeIgniter | Insert Employee Details into MySQL Database</title>
    <!--link the bootstrap css file-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- link jquery ui css-->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/jquery-ui-1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!--include jquery library-->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js'); ?>"></script>
    <!--load jquery ui js file-->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/jquery-ui-1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'); ?>"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
    .colbox {
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
    }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    //load datepicker control onfocus
    $(function() {
        $("#hireddate").datepicker();
    });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-lg-6 col-sm-6 well">
        <legend>Add Department Details</legend>
        <?php 
        $attributes = array("class" => "form-horizontal", "id" => "departmentform", "name" => "departmentform");
        echo form_open("department/index", $attributes);?>
        <fieldset>


            <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row colbox">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
                <label for="department_emer" class="control-label">Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8">
                <input id="department_emer" name="department_emer" placeholder="department_emer" type="text" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo set_value('department_emer'); ?>" />
                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('department_emer'); ?></span>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row colbox">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
                <label for="mbiemer" class="control-label">Description</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="pershkrimi" name="pershkrimi" placeholder="pershkrimi" value="<?php echo set_value('pershkrimi'); ?>" ></textarea>
                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('pershkrimi'); ?></span>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-md-8 text-left">
                <input id="btn_update" name="btn_update" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add" />
                <input id="btn_cancel" name="btn_cancel" type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" value="Cancel" />
            </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
        <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which version of Codeigniter are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In department.php replace

```
$this->db->insert('department', $data);
```

with

```
$this->load->model('department_model.php');
$this->department_model.php->insert($data);
```

And in department_model.php create a function insert

```
public function insert($data) {

    if($this->db->insert('table_name', $data)) {

        //Success message or anything which you want

    }
}
```

This will solve your problem.

Let me know if you require any further help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Please load the CI database library before inserting the data, or you can load it in your constructor method.

```
     $this->load->library('database');
```

Hopefully it can help you.